# Why my code does two instances instead of one?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, instance

Why my code does two instances, one for the parent class and one for the child class. I figure the code in the `main()` ask for only one. I try to unsterstand why that's happen, but no idea coming to my mind to solve this problem...

```
#include <iostream>

class Mother {
public:
    static int instance;
    Mother() {
        std::cout << "Mother constructor" << std::endl;
        instance++;
    }

    int get_instance() {
        return instance;
    }
};

class Child : public Mother {
public:
    Child() {
        std::cout << "Child constructor" << std::endl;
        this->instance++;
    }
};

int Mother::instance = 0;

int main() {
    Child child;
    std::cout << "instance: " <<  Mother::instance << std::endl;
}
```

console return

```
clang++  -std=c++11 -Wconversion *.cpp && ./a.out
Mother constructor
Child constructor
instance<int>: 2
```

Comment: Mother's constructor is called implicitly by Child's constructor.

Comment: Note that inheritance results in an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a), meaning that `Child` is a `Mother`. You might want to think a bit more on whether or not this makes sense in the context of your program/example. See [What is an example of the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle) for more ways the OOP notion of inheritance is at odds with what you may expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Child` *inherits* from `Mother` – i.e., `Mother` is a *base class* of `Child`. Therefore, when you instantiate a `Child` object, `Mother`'s constructor is also called, and it does before the body of `Child`'s constructor is executed.

In your code, both `Mother` and `Child` constructors increase the static data member `instance` by one, that's why after constructing `child`, `instance` value is two instead of one. To obtain the behavior you want, simply don't modify `instance` in `Child::Child()`:

```
class Child: public Mother {
public:
    Child() { std::cout << "Child constructor" << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. My question user:8012646  how many objects I have at the end one or two ? Because I want only one.

Comment: You have one object, `child`, of type `Child` whose base class is `Mother`. Note that a `Child` object can be converted into an object of its base class, `Mother` (i.e., the `Child` object is also a `Mother` object).

Comment: Perfect, it's exactly what I want . I was affraid to take too much place in the memory and maybe create a leak with this situation  when I read the log in the console and I see there is two constructors pass for one object. Thx a lot for your lights !!! user:8012646

Comment: @StanlePunk Note that something analogous happens at destruction: when destroying a `Child` object, `Mother`'s destructor is also called, and it is done after the body of `Child`'s destructor is executed.

Answer (score 0):

When `child` is created, the `Mother` constructor is called first and does `instance++`, then the `Child` constructor is called and does `instance++` again. That's why you get `2`.